# Organize multi-choice user inputs by separate line (not comma)

Tags: sharepoint-online, choice-field, json-formatting, column-formatting

I would like to format a column, so that when a user selects multiple choices, each choice is displayed on a single line rather than separated by comma (,).

I'm looking to leverage JSON formatting for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using below JSON code on your choice field:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=join(@currentField, '\n')"
}
```

**Official documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).

Reference for operators you can use in JSON formatting, [JSON formatting - Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#operators).

**How `join()` works**:

> **join()** takes 2 operands. The first is an **array** (multi-select person or choice field) and the second is the **separating string**.
>
> **Returns a string concatenation of the array** values separated by the separating string.

**Example for multi-select choice field:**

`"txtContent": "=join(@currentField, ', ')"` --> This will result in `Apple, Orange, Cherry` (depending on the selected values)

**Example for multi-select person field:**

`"txtContent": "=join(@currentField.title, '|')"` -->  This will result in `Chris Kent|Vesa Juvonen|Jeff Teper` (depending on the selected persons names).

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=join(@currentField, '\n'"
}
```

A little explanation:

> join: takes 2 operands. The first is an array (multi-select person or
>   choice field) and the second is the separating string. Returns a
>   string concatenation of the array values separated by the separating
>   string. - Only available in SharePoint Online

```
"txtContent": "=join(@currentField, ', ')" might result in "Apple, Orange, Cherry" (depending on the selected values)
"txtContent": "=join(@currentField.title, '|')" might result in "Chris Kent|Vesa Juvonen|Jeff Teper" (depending on the selected persons)
```

Answer (score -1):

As they suggested, use the code they provided on your choice field:

```
{
    "$schema":
    "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=join(@currentField, '\n')"
 }
```

This works for me, the following is my test result:

[image]