# Checkbox List Display

Tags: list, list-view

I've seen the question with no answer to this multi places. Hopefully someone knows the answer.

I have a list with a column of multiple checkbox selections displayed, but it returns each selection in a run on list, like this;

Option 1,Option 2,Option 3

I want it to display:

Option 1

Option 2

Option 3

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online? If Yes, check my answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270490/organize-multi-choice-user-inputs-by-separate-line-not-comma) and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint Online then try using anyone of the below:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=join(@currentField, '\n')"
}
```

**Reference**: [Organize multi-choice user inputs by separate line (not comma)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270490/organize-multi-choice-user-inputs-by-separate-line-not-comma)

**OR**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "display": "block",
        "width": "100%"
      },
      "forEach": "choice in @currentField",
      "txtContent": "[$choice]"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Reference**: [Rendering multi-value Choice fields vertically using JSON Column Formatting](https://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/rendering-multi-value-choice-fields-vertically-using-json-column-formatting)

**Official documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: Hi @Duby, does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will help others in future to find the correct answer easily.