# Text Wrapping using JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am new to this forum.

I have a list that has a choice field with about 20 options (each varying in length). 
I want to display each choice on a new line (text wrap).

Default View looks like this>

[image]

I would prefer it to look like this:

[image]

I heard that JSON formatting on the column might be able to achieve this but I have never used that before.

If you need more information let me know.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check my answers given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270490/organize-multi-choice-user-inputs-by-separate-line-not-comma/270497#270497) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/279097/checkbox-list-display/279099#279099).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using SharePoint Online, you can try using anyone of the below:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=join(@currentField, '\n')"
}
```

**Reference**: [Organize multi-choice user inputs by separate line (not comma)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270490/organize-multi-choice-user-inputs-by-separate-line-not-comma)

**OR**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "display": "block",
        "width": "100%"
      },
      "forEach": "choice in @currentField",
      "txtContent": "[$choice]"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Reference**: [Rendering multi-value Choice fields vertically using JSON Column Formatting](https://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/rendering-multi-value-choice-fields-vertically-using-json-column-formatting)

**Official documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
{
    "$schema":
    "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=join(@currentField, '\n')"
 }
```