# SharePoint multiline column json formatting adding a line break

Tags: sharepoint-online, column-formatting

I have a sharePoint multiline column in a library and added data with a # deliminator. I want to render the data so that where there is a # a line break occurs. So it provide a list and not wrap the text. Is this possible?

I tried changing the # to a html break tag and ran into issues (when I tried to append the data), so perhaps the best option is using json.

**UPDATE** - I've changed the source data to the following format -

```
<div>item1</div><div>item2</div>...
```

In my list view I now can see :

```
item1
item2
item3
```

However the remainder items get cut off in the list view.
Can I add a custom json format, on hover over the cell I can see the complete list. I'm not adding an outer div because it difficult to accomplish using flow. I've looked at MS docs but there is no example where an outer div is not used. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#get-started-with-column-formatting

Comment: There is a `replace()` function in JSON formatting which you can use. But unfortunately it replaces only the first instance. Check the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#operators). Is the number of occurrences of `#` fixed?

Comment: There must be a way to loop, find # then use replace() ?

Comment: Updated question, any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, **forEach** does not support multiple lines of text type.

From **[this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#foreach)**:

The field used in the loop must be in a supported field type with multi-value option enabled: **Person, Lookup, and Choice**.

Since all the text in the multi-line text is recognized as a whole，we couldn't split it via "#" and add the link break between them with Json.

Similar issue:

[Add multiple line breaks to look up column in which multiple values are allowed](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/287424/add-multiple-line-breaks-to-look-up-column-in-which-multiple-values-are-allowed)